# How to show a specific record always at the end?

Tags: sql

I am retrieving data from database on the bases of availability and some items are no longer available, and whenever data shown I want the obsoleted item always at the end.

```
 Item Name    |    Availability
  item1       |       Yes
  item2       |       No
  item3       |       Yes
  item4       |       Yes
```

I want to show those items always at the end that are not available. Like this

```
     Item Name    |    Availability
       item1      |       Yes
       item3      |       Yes
       item4      |       Yes
       item2      |       No
```

Any help for SQL Qry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT [Item Name], Availability
FROM dbo.TableName
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Availability = 'Yes' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
```

<kbd>[**Sql-Server example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6f16/2/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Sort by Availabilty descending (Yes, before No).

```
SELECT [Item Name], Availability
FROM dbo.TableName
ORDER BY Availability DESC, [Item Name] ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6f16/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can add calculated BIT colum 0 for yes and 1 for no, and add order by that bit clolumn clause in your select